# SQL Collation conflict update table

Tags: sql, collation

I have a sql query to update values in my database table using a temp table:

```
Create Table #tmpTbl (Value varchar(30))
insert into #tmpTbl values ('Value1'),('Value2'),('Value3'),('Value4')

Declare @Var2 varchar (250) 
Set @Var2 = 'Variable2' 

Update DB_Table 
Set Var2 = @Var2 
where Var1 in (Select * from #tmpTbl )

drop table #tmpTbl
```

and I get the error

```
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.
```

I have tried adding `collate Latin1_General_CI_AS` to the end of my `create table` statement but the error persist.

How can I resolve this? Or is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 UPDATE DB_TABLE 
SET    VAR2 = @Var2 
WHERE  VAR1 COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT IN (SELECT VALUE COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT 
                                         FROM   #TMPTBL)
```

Comment: @AlexisHong, your welcome :-D

If it works for you, can you please "accept" my answer?